# handling '++' sign in python regex

Tags: python, regex

i have a list of words
i am creating a list of regex objects based on this list of words

```
import re
word = 'This is word of spy++'
wl = ['spy++','cry','fpp']
regobjs = [re.compile(r"\b%s\b" % word.lower() ) for word in wl]

for reobj in regobjs:
    print re.search(regobj, word).group()
```

but i am getting error`(error: multiple repeat)` while creating regex objs because of the signs ++
how do i make the regex to handle all the cases of words in the word list ?

```
    requirements:

       regex should detect the exact word from the given text
 even if the word having non alpha numeric chars like (++) above code detect the exact words except those having ++ char.
```

Comment: You need [`re.escape()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape).

Comment: @SvenMarnach: He needs more than that...

Comment: @Sashi Nobody wants to obtain errors. Wanting "not to obtain" doesn't bring information on what one wants "to obtain". Writing _"handle all the cases"_ is super vague

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides `re.escape()` you also need to remove the `\b` word boundaries before/after a non-alphanumeric character, or the match will fail.

Something like this (not very elegant, but I hope it gets the point across):

```
import re
words = 'This is word of spy++'
wl = ['spy++','cry','fpp']
regobjs = []

for word in wl:
    eword = re.escape(word.lower())
    if eword[0].isalnum() or eword[0]=="_":
        eword = r"\b" + eword
    if eword[-1].isalnum() or eword[-1]=="_":
        eword = eword + r"\b"
    regobjs.append(re.compile(eword))

for regobj in regobjs:
    print re.search(regobj, words).group()
```

Comment: But does it works if i want to match exact word in the given string thats why i have added \b.

Comment: it is not doing exact match which is doing in presence of \b need both option \b as well as re.escape() or is their any alternate solution?

Comment: Sorry, removed my last comment, it not working for Python. Python does not even accept alternations in its lookbehinds.

Comment: @Tim Didn't you test this code ? One must add an ``s`` to the names _word_ in ``word = 'This is word of spy++'`` and ``print re.search(regobj, word).group()`` in order that this code work coreectly , otherwise it collides with _word_ of the loop. - And by the way, _regobj_ instead of _reobj_ ...

Comment: @Tim If we suppose that Sashi wants to find substrings whose first and last character are characters belonging to what is defined as word in the doc of the symbol ``\b`` (that is to say: _"A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore characters"_ ) , the tests ``if eword[0].isalnum()`` and ``if eword[-1].isalnum()`` must be added with ``or eword[0]=='_'`` and ``or eword[-1]=='_'`` - But it seems that Sashi wants in reality to find words defined as delimited by blank space or whitespace.

Comment: @eyquem: Thanks, serves me right for testing isolated pieces of the code and then pasting them together without checking for name collisions. Thanks also for the `isalnum()` hint; I had thought that it checks for the same characters as `\w` in a regex does, apparently I was mistaken. As for the correct behaviour when looking at words that end in a non-alnum character, I don't know what @Shashi wants it to be. As you wrote in your comment to Duncan's answer, his requirements are unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `\b` when your word begins or ends with a letter, digit or underscore, and `\B` when it doesn't. That will mean you don't pick up `spy++x` for example but would pick up `spy++.` or even `spy+++`. If you want to avoid the last of those then things are going to get much more complicated.

```
>>> def match_word(word):
    return re.compile("%s%s%s" % (
        "\\b" if word[0].isalnum() or word[0]=='_' else "\\B",
        re.escape(word.lower()),
        "\\b" if word[-1].isalnum() or word[-1]=='_' else "\\B"))

>>> text = 'This is word of spy++'
>>> wl = ['spy++','cry','fpp', 'word']
>>> for word in wl:
    match = re.search(match_word(word), text)
    if match:
        print(repr(match.group()))
    else:
        print("{} did not match".format(word))


'spy++'
cry did not match
fpp did not match
'word'
```

Comment: Your code detects _spy++_ in _'word of !spy++'_ , in _'word of spy++!'_ , and in _'word of spy+++++'_ . I'm not sure it is what Sashi wants. In fact , his requirement is confused.

Comment: @eyquem yes the requirement is confusing. If he specified the exact rules for boundaries between words and non-words then it might be possible to match those rules.

Answer (score 1):

Sashi,

Your question is poor, it doesn't express what you exactly want. Then people are tempted to deduct what you want from the content of your code, and that leads to confusion.

I suppose that you want to find occurences of words in the list **wl** when they are purely isolated in a string, that is to say without any non-whitespace around each occurence.

If so , I propose the regex's pattern in the following code:

```
import re

ss = 'spy++ This !spy++ is spy++! word of spy++'
print ss
print [mat.start() for mat in re.finditer('spy',ss)]
print


base = ('(?:(?<=[ \f\n\r\t\v])|(?<=\A))'
        '%s'
        '(?=[ \f\n\r\t\v]|\Z)')

for x in ['spy++','cry','fpp']:
    print x,[mat.start() for mat in re.finditer(base % re.escape(x),ss)]
```

result

```
spy++ This !spy++ is spy++! word of spy++
[0, 12, 21, 36]

spy++ [0, 36]
cry []
fpp []
```